# React Router navigated-to-page appears below current page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I am using React JS and React Router.

Here is my code:

**Here is the SomeComponent file:**

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{

    //some code
    
    
    render(){
        return(
            
                <div className="somecomponent">
                    <h1>some heading</h1>
                </div>  
        );
    }

}

export default SomeClass;
```

**Here is my App.js file:**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import SomeComponent from './components/SomeComponent';
class SomeClass extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
       //some code
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <h1>ABC</h1>
                    <label htmlFor="name">Your name</label>
                    <input className="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" />
                    <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push("/somepath/component")}>Click Me</button>
                </form>
                    
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/somepath/component" component={SomeComponent} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }

}

export default SomeClass;
```

**Here is my index.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
    (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    ),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**The layout:**

**Here is the App.js component:**

[image: App.js page]

**Here is the component at the following link: "/somepath/component":**
[image: SomeComponent page]

**When I click on the "Click Me" button, both components appear on the top of each other.**
[image: After button is clicked]

**My Question:**

When I click on the button, it directs me to the page at the following link: "/somepath/component"
However, the problem is that the page appears below the previous page.

I want to have the previous page disappear, after navigating to the new page.

Comment: Hi, im little bit lost in those code snippets you included, but i think the issue is in your `App.js` file. The part with form will be rendered with every page because there isn't any condition for this page not to be rendered. To solve this issue you can extract this form logic to a `YourNewFormComponent` and add something like `<Route path="/form-page" component={YourNewFormComponent} />` to `App.ts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift the `form` component in `app.js` in to another page

```
render(){
    return(
        <Router>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h1>ABC</h1>
                <label htmlFor="name">Your name</label>
                <input className="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" />
                <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push("/somepath/component")}>Click Me</button>
            </form>
                
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={FormComponent} />
                <Route exact path="/somepath/component" component={SomeComponent} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

The `FormComponent` being:

```
render(){
    return(
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h1>ABC</h1>
                <label htmlFor="name">Your name</label>
                <input className="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" />
                <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push("/somepath/component")}>Click Me</button>
            </form>
    );
}
```

Also make sure `event.preventDefault` is called in `handleSubmit` to avoid page reload on form submit.

the path `path="/"` will only show the `FormComponent` initially and remove it when path changes.

**In case `form` component has to be in `app.js`:**

You need to manually hide the component. So, modify `app.js` something like:

```
return (
    <>
        {this.props.location.pathname === '/' && (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h1>ABC</h1>
                <label htmlFor="name">Your name</label>
                <input className="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" />
                <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/somepath/component')}>
                    Click Me
                </button>
            </form>
        )}
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/somepath/component" component={SomeComponent} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </>
)
```

In case `location` prop is not present, import `withRouter` hoc and wrap it over `App`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
...
export default withRouter(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `form` element is not on routed component. If you worte like this, `form` will be always visible (and `SomeComponent` will appears always on bottom of `form`). You should move the `form` into a component. Something like:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component{
  ...
  render(){
   return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <h1>ABC</h1>
         <label htmlFor="name">Your name</label>
         <input className="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" />
         <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push("/somepath/component")}>Click Me</button>
      </form>
   );
  }
}
export default FormComponent;
```

Then in App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import SomeComponent from './components/SomeComponent';
import FormComponent from './components/FormComponent';
class SomeClass extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
       //some code
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={FormComponent} />
                    <Route exact path="/somepath/component" component={SomeComponent} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }

}

export default SomeClass;
```

Comment: I lifted up the state, so I had to move the form to App.js

Comment: @abc_123 I understand but if you leave the `form` there you will always see the `form` independently if you change route.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: @abc_123 no problem. Have a nice coding =)